# Majorana modes at the edge of a QSHI

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-insulators, majorana-fermions

I am currently looking at Fu and Kane paper: Phys. Rev. B 79, 161408(R).

They write the QSHI edge states as
$H_{\text{edge}}=\psi^{\dagger}(-iv\sigma_{z}\partial_{x})\psi$

where $\psi=(\psi_{\uparrow},\psi_{\downarrow})^{T}$.

upon adding s-wave SC term, they wrote the Bogoliubov de-Gennes Hamiltonian (with $\mu=0$) as
$H=\frac{1}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}h\Psi$

where $\Psi=(\psi_{\uparrow},\psi_{\downarrow},\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger},-\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger})^{T} $ and $h=-iv\tau_{z}\sigma_{z}\partial_{x}+\Delta_0\tau_x$

where $\sigma$ acts in the spin space and $\tau$ acts in the particle hole space (Pauli matrices).
Now, the weird thing is that if I look only at the edge term it does not return to the original one in terms of $\psi$. What I get instead is

$H_{0}=\frac{1}{2}\Psi^{\dagger}h_{0}\Psi=\frac{1}{2}(\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger},\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger},\psi_{\downarrow},-\psi_{\uparrow})(-iv\tau_{z}\sigma_{z}\partial_{x})\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi_{\uparrow}\\
\psi_{\downarrow}\\
\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}\\
-\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}
\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger},\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger},\psi_{\downarrow},-\psi_{\uparrow})(-iv\partial_{x})\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi_{\uparrow}\\
-\psi_{\downarrow}\\
-\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}\\
-\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}
\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}(-iv\partial_{x})\psi_{\uparrow}+\psi_{\uparrow}(-iv\partial_{x})\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}-\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}(-iv\partial_{x})\psi_{\downarrow}-\psi_{\downarrow}(-iv\partial_{x})\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger})=?$

whereas the edge Hamiltonian is

$H=\psi^{\dagger}(-iv\sigma_{z}\partial_{x})\psi=H=(\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger},\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger})(-iv\sigma_{z}\partial_{x})\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi_{\uparrow}\\
\psi_{\downarrow}
\end{array}\right)=(\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger},\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger})(-iv\partial_{x})\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi_{\uparrow}\\
-\psi_{\downarrow}
\end{array}\right)=\psi_{\uparrow}^{\dagger}(-iv\partial_{x})\psi_{\uparrow}-\psi_{\downarrow}^{\dagger}(-iv\partial_{x})\psi_{\downarrow}$

I don't see what went wrong here, I would be glad if someone could help me resolve this.

Comment: What you are writing is the Hamiltonian density. The actual Hamiltonian in your notation is $\int dx H$. When you obtain terms such as $\psi \partial_x \psi^\dagger$, you need to carefully do integration by parts to put them into the canonical form $\psi^\dagger \partial_x \psi$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh I see this now, so I get minus sign from integrating by parts and one for exchange + some other constant terms. So overall it works fine. Thanks!